# Water Properties IAPWS-IF97 implementation on C/C++

Tags: c

I'm Looking for an implementation of the IAPWS-IF97 water properties on C/C++.
I'm aware of the library [freesteam](http://freesteam.sourceforge.net/). However freesteam does not include all the properties I'm looking for. Particularly I need differential properties like dh/dp, dv/dp and in certain regions. I use a similar implementation for Octave/Matlab and I would also like to have it in C/C++.

Comment: Since someone already did almost all of the work for you, why not compute these derivatives by finite differences? Or implement these derivatives in freesteam yourself?

Comment: (...and then of course contribute the upstream for inclusion in that project.)

Answer (score 1):

If you could only use Java, our open source IF97 library provides partial derivatives, see: [www.hummeling.com/IF97](http://www.hummeling.com/IF97)

And it can be used for proprietary software as well.